# How do I convert this aspx snippet to razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm very comfortable with Aspx, not such much with razor. But i'm working on a project that requires razor, and I'm struggling with this conversion. Could someone write this so it's razor friendly? In some razor examples it seems like you don't have to declare the lambda expression, others use a @`<text>` or @:. I'm so confused.

```
 <%
            Html.Telerik()
                .ListView(productsToShow)
                .Name("AmazonProducts")
                .PrefixUrlParameters(false)
                .BeginLayout(pager =>
                                {%>
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <%})
                .BeginGroup(() =>
                                {%>
                                <tr>
                                <%})
                .Item(model =>
                                { %>
                                <td>
                                   ...stuff...
                                </td>
                                <%})
                .EmptyItem(() =>{%><%})
                .EndGroup(() =>
                                {%>
                                </tr>
                                <%})
                .EndLayout(pager =>
                                {%>
                                </table>
                                <%})
                                .GroupItemCount(2)
                                .PageSize(productsToShow.Count)
                                .Render();
    %>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is replace the `<%` with `@{` and the `%>` with `}`, and this should work fine.  I agree with @Erik, Stack Overflow is not a code translation service, so perhaps try rephrasing your question a little differently next time (like "What is the difference between `@text` and `@:` in Razor, and how do I specify a code block?").

If you want a good introduction to Razor, try Scott Guthrie's excellent introduction to Razor:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

If you want my take on why Razor is better than ASPX, and why you should be using it, you can read the blog post I wrote about it here:

http://blogs.popart.com/2011/06/razor-is-better/

Comment: I would love for that to be the case because it looks nice and easy, but alas. .net was not happy with that. Plus, it looks very odd to have opening and closing brackets back to back like that: .BeginLayout(pager => { } <table> @{})